# Can IO actions be sequenced while keeping the logic in a pure function?

Tags: haskell, monads, servant

I have the following code which grabs two pages of data from a paginated API endpoint. I'd like to modify `query` function to keep getting pages until it finds no more data (so replace `take 2` in the code below with something which looks at the API response).

My question is wether it is possible to achieve this without changing `query` function to an `IO` function. And if so, how would I go about it. If not, is there a way of doing this without writing recursive function?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant.Client
import Network.HTTP.Client (newManager, defaultManagerSettings)

import Data.Proxy
import Servant.API

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics


-- data type
data BlogPost = BlogPost
  { id :: Integer
  , title :: String
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON BlogPost


-- api client
type API = "posts" :> QueryParam "_page" Integer :> Get '[JSON] [BlogPost]
api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy
posts :: Maybe Integer -> ClientM [BlogPost]
posts = client api


-- query by page
query :: ClientM [[BlogPost]]
query = sequence $ take 2 $ map posts pages
  where
    pages = [Just p | p <- [1..]]

-- main
main :: IO ()
main = do
  manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  let url = ClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" 80 "")
  posts' <- runClientM query url
  print posts'
```

---

I've tried to use `takeWhileM` to do this and ended up making query an `IO` function and passing `url` into it. It was starting to look pretty horrible and I couldn't get the types to match up (I felt like I needed something more like `(a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> m [a]` rather than `(a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]` which is what `takeWhileM` is - still find this strange because I see this function as a filter, yet the input list and output list are different (one has monad around it and the other doesn't)).

Comment: Once in IO, always in IO. What did you try with `takeWhileM` that didn't work?

Comment: `ClientM` [is _already_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/Servant-Client.html#control.i:id:ClientM:MonadIO:4) a (transformer-enhanced) IO monad. You can just execute any `IO` action in it with [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO).

Comment: This really sounds like something I'm after @leftaroundabout, but I'm really struggling to replace my `take 2` with something with `liftIO`. Could you elaborate a bit more please? Sorry, real haskell noob here :|

Answer (score 4):

For these cases of monadic iteration I usually turn to the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html) library. Its interface is reminiscent to that of pure lists, while still allowing effects:

```
import           Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude               as S

repeatAndCollect :: Monad m => m (Either a r) -> m [a]
repeatAndCollect = S.toList_ . Control.Monad.void . S.untilRight

repeatAndCollectLimited :: Monad m => Int -> m (Either a r) -> m [a]
repeatAndCollectLimited len = S.toList_ . S.take len . S.untilRight
```

Using the [`untilRight`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:untilRight), [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:take) and [`toList_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:toList_) functions.

---

When only the first successful result is needed, we can use the `Alternative` instance of the [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT) transformer in combination with [`asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) from `Data.Foldable` to execute a list of fallible actions until one of them succeeds.

`IO` itself has an `Alternative` instance that returns the first "success", where "failure" means throwing a `IOException`.

Comment: In the next version of `streaming`, that `void` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: This is a cool approach, but how do I get `len` for `S.take len`? I don't know what it should be in advance - I should stop fetching data once the last fetch returns an empty list.

Comment: @zoran119 That `len` in `repeatAndCollectLimited` is only for setting a maximum number of iterations. The other way of stopping is when the action returns a `Right` (this is the only way `repeatAndCollect` can stop).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `unfoldM`?

```
unfoldM :: Monad m => m (Maybe a) -> m [a]
```

Let's update `posts` this way

```
posts :: Maybe Integer -> ClientM (Maybe [BlogPost])
posts = fmap notNil . client api where
  notNil [] = Nothing
  notNil bs = Just bs
```

The idea is to update `query` so that you can just use `unfoldM query` and get back an `ClientM [[BlogPost]]`. To do that, the type of `query` has to be

```
query :: ClientM (Maybe [BlogPost])
```

meaning, the page number must be coming from the environment:

```
query = forever $ page >>= posts
```

Clearly, there is some form of state going on here, as we need a way to keep track of the current page number. We can wrap the client action in a `StateT`:

```
type ClientSM = StateT Integer ClientM

page :: ClientSM Integer
page = get <* modify (+1)
```

This action demands a few additional changes to both `query` and `posts`. **Edit: see below for a stroke of insight I got in the bus.** First we need to lift the client action in the state monad:

```
posts :: Integer -> ClientSM (Maybe [BlogPost])
posts = fmap notNil . lift . client api . Just  where
  notNil [] = Nothing
  notNil xs = Just xs
```

Only the type of `query` needs changing

```
query :: ClientSM (Maybe [BlogPost])
```

Finally, the main action just needs to peel the monad stack and unfold the query:

```
main = do
  manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  let url = mkClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" 80 "")
  result <- flip runClientM url $ flip runStateT 1 $ unfoldM query
  case result of
    Left error -> print error
    Right (posts, _) -> print posts
```

I haven't tested this, but it compiles

---

`posts` is oblivious to the state, and should remain so. So, without changing my original version above, you just need to lift in `query`:

```
query :: ClientSM (Maybe [BlogPost])
query = forever $ page >>= lift . posts . Just
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the `ClientM` objects separate (either to run them each in a clean state, or anything similar), the best way is to chain your operations together.
In this particular case, the `runClientM query ...` IO action returns a `Either String [BlogPost]`. This means that the stop condition is receiving a `Left String` from one of the computations.

<s>Using a hand-crafted `eitherM` helper, which runs one of two actions depending on the `Either` contructor, here is a relatively simple example of that:</s>
Using the good old either makes this relatively simple :

```
queryAll :: ClientEnv -> [Int] -> IO [[BlogPost]]
queryAll _ [] = return []
queryAll url (x:xs) = runClientM (posts x) url >>= either ((const.pure) []) (\b -> (b:) <$> queryAll url xs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  let url = ClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" 80 "")
  posts' <- queryAll url [1..]
  print posts'
```

Hope it can help! :)

Comment: `eitherM` is the same as `either`. Using `>>=` with `case` (or `LambdaCase`) or just writing a `do` block would be fine as well.